# Tokenizing a string in Kotlin

Tags: regex, string, replace, tokenize, kotlin

I have a sql query string to create or replace a trigger for an Oracle DB that looks like this...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER schema.trigger_name 
    BEFORE DELETE ON schema.table_c 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO table_h (col_1, 
                              col_2, 
                              col_3, 
                              col_4) 
        VALUES (val_1,
                val_2,
                val_3,
                val_4) 
    END
```

I'm trying to remove all of the SQL keywords so that I am left with a map looking something like...

```
{trigger_name "schema.trigger_name",
 on_table     "schema.table_c",
 hist_table   "schema.table_h",
 cols         ["col_1", ... ],
 values       ["val_1", ... ]}
```

I'm trying right now to use a regular expression to remove all of the keywords and then I'll be able to split the remaining string up accordingly. My replace looks like this...

```
val r = s.replace(
        "^(BEFORE DELETE ON" +
        "|CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER" +
        "|BEGIN" +
        "|INSERT INTO" +
        "|VALUES" +
        "|END)", "")
```

Where s is the string that I gave above. When I run this, there is no change in the output. I'm not very good at regex (I very rarely use it), so it wouldn't be a shock to hear that mine is absolutely wrong. I'm also very new to Kotlin, so if there is a more idiomatic way to do this (which I'm sure there is) I would be very excited to learn!

Comment: You're not using any regex in the above code. You replacing a substring literal (which doesn't exist), by an empty string. Read the api doc: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html. If you want to use a regex, then you need to pass a Regex instance as argument.

Comment: Immediately after asking the question I found the "".toRegex() function... Today's been a rough day... Thanks so much for your answers.

Comment: regex is not the best model for this, there are SQL parsers out there such as [Apache Calcite](https://calcite.apache.org/) or using Antlr and one of the existing gramar files to create one.